# How to create a new unique value in DB context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a table as follow

**Events**:

```
ID  IDTask  DateTime
-------------------------------------------
1   1       December 6th 2021, 10:15:21.086
2   1       December 6th 2021, 10:16:21.086
3   2       December 6th 2021, 11:15:21.086
4   1       December 7th 2021, 10:15:21.086
5   3       December 7th 2021, 10:17:21.086
6   3       December 8th 2021, 10:19:21.086
```

Basically, tasks are being done and I want to record events about these tasks.

For that, I created a table which add a new entry every time a new event is recorded. The issue is that I can have multiple event with the same `IDTask`, but I would like to be able to tell the DbContext "Take the 1st unused value available".

```
public bool CreateWareHouseEvent(CallContext callContext, int? TaskID, string Comment)
{
    var warehouseEvent = new Domain.DataService.Contract.Model.WarehouseEvent();
    warehouseEvent.TaskId = TaskID ?? default(int);
    warehouseEvent.UserId = int.Parse(callContext.User);
    warehouseEvent.Comment = Comment;
    warehouseEvent.DateTask = DateTime.Now;

    DbContext.WarehouseEvents.Add(warehouseEvent)
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can I change the `?? default(int)` to instead get the 1st unused value? So if I don't tell him which task it's part of, it just create a new task for it.

Comment: Does it make sense to have an event without a Task? Does your database table allows TaskID to be null? If not why do you allow your method  to have a nullable taskID?

Comment: That should **really** be handled properly, in the database, by using something like an `IDENTITY` column, or a `SEQUENCE` in the database.

Comment: @Steve The database doesn't accept nullable. The function did because I would consider a "null" as meaning to create a new value. warehouseEvent.TaskId is not nullable. TaskID is. (the parameter)

Comment: @marc_s I guess I owe my old SQL teacher for that one. I don't remember him talking about Sequences, but I believe this might be the solution. I'll look into those and see how to go about sequences in entity framework. Thank you

Comment: Sequences were introduced in SQL Server **2012** - so they have been around for a while, but you're not alone - I've seen a great many SQL Server devs and dbas still being surprised by this "new" feature ;-)